# How can I wrap a Node executable's output in a pager?

Tags: node.js, command-line, pagination, executable, command-line-interface

I've got a command-line interface to my Node.js library that can produce somewhat long output.

I'd like to include the traditional `--no-pager` flag, and then automatically wrap my executable in the system `$PAGER`. In Ruby, I'd have used [`exec()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec), or Python's [`os.execv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execv); but Node's `child_process.exec()` has a completely different meaning *(ugh, by the way.)*

At the moment, the only robust and cross-platform way I can think of to achieve this, is to write an Node extension that basically implements Ruby's process-replacing `exec()`. That sounds like a serious undertaking; so any other outside-the-box ideas are extremely welcomed. (=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at node kexec https://github.com/jprichardson/node-kexec. It lets you spawn a child process that will replace the current process.

Comment: This worked out well for me, actually. For future visitors, [here's the specifics](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/Paws.js/commit/63ba228#diff-1140573f8a72164f398667e9ba3a935fR175) of how I implemented it.